# sort function in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

sorting a column in spark dataframe having two and three digit numbers.

I am sorting a column having integer type with two and three digit numbers, after applying sort() on the amount column, it is displaying three digit number on top and then all the two digit numbers are sorted below it. Kindly explain how to sort the complete column in the right way.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't pase images but rather the code so it's easier for everyone to read it and copy/paste it. You can edit your post to do so.

Comment: Then, it seems you tried various things already. What results did you got for instance when casting the column to integer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't use the latest df to sort,

you used the df before coverting the amount to int.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, can you please provide the schema of dataframe sortdf on line no. 3 in above code ?

Second, on line no. 4 I see you creating a new dataframe with intdf with column 'amount' cast to Int. can you share the schema of intdf dataframe.
Correct syntax for creating intdf dataframe is:

val intdf = sortdf.withcolumn("amount", col("amount").cast("Integer"))

You can use intdf.printschema() function.

Third, you not using the dataframe created in line no.4 i.e intdf to execute the sort command on it. Likely the datatype of 'amount' column in sortdf is not int and so you not getting the right output.

suggest you use:

val sdf = intdf.sort(col('amount').desc) to get the your desired result.